# i cannot get the selected values from the listbox in to valiable (using loop).it is getting attahced message.my code as below

Tags: c#

[image]

```
String strItem;
foreach (DataRowView selecteditem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    strItem = selecteditem.ToString();

    //Process(strItem);
    MessageBox.Show(strItem);
}
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", selecteditem.Row.ItemArray));`

Comment: thankz Tim,seems it is Ok so how can I assigned the selected value to the variable

Answer (score 0):

To use your row as a string your should try

```
strItem = String.Join(", ", selecteditem.Row.ItemArray);
```